# Lua error: 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 58) near <eof>

Tags: lua

I keep getting this error: 'end expected (to close function at line 58) near eof error and don't know how to fix it. Please let me know if you know the answer to this code because I've been stumped for hours upon hours

```
function update(dt)
    if emit then
        local radius = 0.4
        local life = 5.0
        local emitPeriod = 1
        local count = 6
        local vel = 8
        local drag = 0.3
        local gravity = 0.0
        local red = 0.55
        local green = 0.5
        local blue = 0.45
        local vol = 0.3
        local alpha = 0.7

        --Modify according to settings
        local propTime = GetString("savegame.mod.time")
        if propTime == "10 " .. GetTranslatedStringByKey("UI_SECONDS") then
            emitPeriod = 10
        
        elseif propTime == "20 " .. GetTranslatedStringByKey("Sec") then
                emitPeriod = 20
                
        elseif propTime == GetTranslatedStringByKey("INFINITE") then
            emitPeriod = 1000000
        end
        
        local propAmount = GetString("savegame.mod.amount")
        if propAmount == GetTranslatedStringByKey("A_LITTLE") then
            count = 4
            vel = 5
            radius = 0.3
            vol = 0.1
            alpha = 0.4
        elseif propAmount == GetTranslatedStringByKey("A_LOT") then             
            count = 8
            vel = 10
            radius = 0.5
            vol = 0.5
            alpha = 1.0
        elseif propAmount == GetTranslatedStringByKey("HOLY_SHIT") then             
            count = 12
            vel = 10
            radius = 1
            vol = 1
            alpha = 1.0
        end
```

Comment: All blocks in Lua, including `if` and `function` blocks, need an accompanying `end` to close the block. Your `if emit then` and `function update(dt)` are missing such `end`s.